# JDBI interval postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

How properly use such query with date intervals

```
 @SqlUpdate("delete fromlogin where created < now() - ':days days' :: interval")
 void deleteOldLogin(@Bind("days") Period days);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't pass the number of days inside an interval constant as a parameter. You need to pass an integer specifying your number of days, then multiply that with an interval of the desired length.

```
@SqlUpdate("delete fromlogin where created < now() - :days * '1 day'::interval")
```

Answer (score 1):

Jdbi now supports binding the `java.time.Duration` type as an `interval`: https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/pull/670